# How to find all solutions of $x^2-y^2=x+y$?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

For this equation $$x^2-y^2=x+y$$ I know there are 2 functional solutions, $y=x-1$, and $y=-x$.

The second solution we can see immediately because both sides will always be $0$.

The first solution is also easy to get:$$(x-y)(x+y)=x+y\ \ ///\div(x+y)\ \ \ [y\neq-x]\\x-y=1\\y=x-1$$
But how do I solve this in a formal way? So that I'll find all solutions, and show that there aren't other solutions?

Comment: Note that $$(x^2-y^2)-(x+y)=(x+y)(x-y-1)$$ hence the LHS is zero if and only if one factor on the RHS is.

Comment: Right, I should have factor out $x+y$ instead of dividing it. Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a theorem stating that degree two polynomial equations of two variables with real coefficients describe either conic sections or a pair of straight lines.

Comment: Nothing wrong with dividing.  As long as you make two case 1) where x +y ne 0 and you divide; and 2) where x + y = 0 and you don't divide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y) = x+y$

If $x+y=0$ then all $\{(x, -x)|x \in \mathbb R\}$ are solutions.

If $x+y\ne 0$ then $(x-y) = 1$ and $y = x -1$ so all $\{(x, x-1)|x \in \mathbb R\}$ are solutions.

So solutions are $\{(x, -x)|x \in \mathbb R\}\cup\{(x, x-1)|x \in \mathbb R\}$.

....

or $x^2 - y^2 = x+y$

$x^2 - y^2 -(x+y) = 0$

$(x+y)[(x-y) - 1] = 0$

so either $x+y = 0$ or $x-y-1 = 0$ so....

Comment: In the third line you meant "If $x+y\neq 0$", right?

Comment: I must certainly did.